# How to test a non variable taking recursive method in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, rspec

Here's the code waiting testing, seems like a chicken egg problem.

```
def generate_number
  number = Array.new(8){rand(10)}.join
  return number unless Book.exists?(:number => number)
  generate_number
end
```

Add a variable into the method will be easy to handle this, but I think there might be a better way to solve this.

Comment: Not a solution for your problem, but why is your method recursive to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns a random string, so you can't test for explicit returned value. What you can test is that:

1. the method returns a string consisting of 8 digits
2. the string that method returned is not a number of any existing book